# Mathematical theory of plasma

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, nonlinear-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, special-relativity

I am working on a heavily mathematically project about plasma. In particular, I want to find references that treat the problem from microscopic models that include relativistic and magnetic effects (Coulomb forces, QFT, etc) and obtain kinetic models (BBGKY, Landau equation, Maxwells equation, etc). What are some state  of the art papers/references?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange may be a better forum for this question, as they will be more familiar with plasma physics books at differing levels of mathematical treatment

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I am looking for mathematical references similar to what we have in kinetic theory of gases or for the Boltzmann equation... physicists treat these problems in a completely different way and their methods are more of "statistical mechanics" than "kinetic theory". But I will also ask the question in physics stack.

Comment: The main hurdle seems to be you are still asking from a physicists' point of view by mentioning overarching physical theories of which a mathematician in the field would only have a passing awareness. I think a good starting point would be textbooks concerning magnetohydrodynamics or continuum mechanics in charged media since they seem to be more math oriented and will certainly have citations to, or be cited by, other papers that you are looking for. From a physics perspective, I can never recommend [this book](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/7881#t=aboutBook) enough.